# Without using `overflow:hidden` how can I create two horizontally adjacent divs, where div2 takes up width space remaining from div1

Tags: css

I want to create a layout with 2 horizontal divs that follow these rules:

1. `#left` has precedent on width (adjusts width to size of contents), and `#right` takes up the remaining width to the right
2. Does not use `overflow:hidden` due to dropdown menus

I created this fiddle to demonstrate the issue: **http://jsfiddle.net/7GcRD/**. It uses `#right{overflow:hidden;}` to demonstrate what I want it to look like. To show that your solution works, you need to remove `#right{overflow:hidden;}` from the CSS in the example.

Despite reading these two resources, I was not able to resolve the issue:

1. http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Either the suggestions caused the full width not to be taken up by the **right** div, or caused a scrollbar to appear in the **right** div.

Comment: What you have seems to be working fine to me...

Comment: why not float:right for the second box?

Comment: @Rakesh, it does not satisfy rule 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:  http://jsfiddle.net/designbymichael/VnLGX/1/

It uses jQuery to detect the width of your left box dynamically, even on the change of window size, and adjusts the right box accordingly.  You could also use that function for any other event listeners in your page as well.

Note that I've also added a container div around your left and right boxes, removed the float (we shouldn't have to care about that anymore), changed the width to auto, and then used absolute positioning for the right box.

Here is the function that I'm using to evaluate box width and adjust accordingly:

```
function adjustBoxes() {
   var paddingWidth = 10;  // set this to adjust distance between boxes
   var leftWidth = $('#left').width();  // get left box width
   var docWidth = $(document).width();  // get document width
   var difference = docWidth - leftWidth; // set the difference
    $('#right').width(difference - paddingWidth);
}
```